# HashNavigation in cordova wp8 hangs app

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8, chaplinjs

I have next code

```
function navigate(_hash){
   alert('before');

   //try#1
   window.location.hash = _hash;
   //try#2
   // window.location.href=window.location.href.split("#")[0]+"#" +url;

   alert('after');

}

navigate('someurl')
```

the issue is that after changing url hash (both variants) app just hangs. And interesting thing that **second** alert is not firing. so app just... crashes after some time.
Nothing in js console.
Debug log says

> The thread 0x*** has exited with code 259 (0x103).

google found nothing on that. Seems like this is acommon error code.
More details: 
i'm using ChaplinJs so just can't get away from hash navigation.

second thought was that chaplin overloads system and we caanot get anywhere, but(!) putting logs and alerts in source of lib   in window.on('hashchange',....)   also didn't make any effort because we do not get there also.

**WP 8.0**
tried both Cordova 4.*  and 5.*
also tried to modify xhrXelper.cs   but it is not related tonavigation itself.

PS: I know that jquery mobile suggests to disable hashchanges onmobile navigation. But i can't :(

PPS:   also tried todisable chaplin haschanges

```
new App({routes: routes, controllerSuffix: '-controller', pushState: false,hashChange:true})
```

but this also didn't make any good results because  it's placing hash to href to check it in interval and app hanged again. So i assume that is a webview problem

**More additional info: 
continious re-run of app makes it work sometimes (1 run of 10 can make it work).** That's very strange.

**Emulator and device behave in the same way.**

Update: Read somewhere that it's critical  to restrict navigting before "deviceready" event.
But this is also not a case.

Update2: create cordova proj from scratch. Added hash change indeviceready cb and it hangs

Update3: same code on 8.1 works perfect